# Need count with group by

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have attached order table, Please find below. I need a count value 4, can you help me make a SQL query

Note : status = 1 and order_id should count only one time if order_id available with more than one row

[image]

Comment: What are you counting?

Answer (score 0):

Count the distinct `order_id`s with `status = 1`:

```
select count(distinct order_id) total_count
from tablename
where status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT <column>)`. For example:

```
select count(distinct order_id) from t where status = 1
```